# JMS serializer - deserializing doctrine entity with reference by id not working

Tags: symfony, serialization, doctrine-orm, deserialization, jmsserializerbundle

is it possible to deserialize this json object and set the "place" reference only by id in one request? :

```
{
  "title": "some title",
  "description" : "some description",
  "place" : {
     "id" : "5367ffcd3271d87f5c7b23cf" // mongoid to one-to-many reference object
   } 
}
```

in this case jms serializer giving me: Cannot create a `DBRef` without an identifier. `UnitOfWork::getDocumentIdentifier()` did not return an identifier for class `Path\Document\Place (500 Internal Server Error)`

Ok, i understand it. when i posting json object with properties like latitude, longitude and other than id everything working perfectly -> reference "child" Place object is created.

My question is -> what if i want to create reference with existing object only by indication via "id" in one single request using JMS with deserialize method?

Thanks for your help and sorry for my english.

---

i solved this by setting place object in @PostDeserialize action if isset place ID.